# mwEmbed player not getting for uploaded video in MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

In MediaWiki I am uploaded the video and I need to add the mwEmbed video player for the uploaded video. I add the MwEmbedSupport extension and define in `LocalSettings.php`, we need to know how to customize the player for the uploaded video.

Answer (score 0):

[See here](http://mediawikibootstrapskin.co.uk/demo/index.php?title=Mediawiki_Youtube_Plugin) Perhaps not an ideal solution if you're using Vector, but it appears to be relatively easy to install.

Comment: shanmugam2138 said the video is uploaded locally.